# openpyxl - "copy/paste" range of cells

Tags: python, copy-paste, openpyxl, excel-automation

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to adapt some of my VBA code to it using the openpyxl library. On this particular case, I'm trying to copy 468 rows in a single column from a workbook according to the string in the header and to paste them in another workbook in a particular column that has another specific string as a header. I can't simply select the range of cells I want to copy because this is part of a report automation and the headers change positions from file to file.

What's the function I need to use to copy each of the 468 cells from one workbook into the 468 cells of the second workbook? Or alternatively how can I copy a range of cells and then paste them in another workbook? Here is my code and I know exactly what's wrong: I'm copying one cell (the last from the first workbook) repeatedly into the 468 cells of the second workbook.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pdb
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('.../Extraction.xlsx')
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('.../Template.xlsx')

ws1 = wb1.active
first_row1 = list(ws1.rows)[0]             #to select the first row (header)
for cell in first_row1:
    if cell.value == "email":
        x = cell.column                    #to get the column
        y = column_index_from_string(x)    #to get the column's index

for i in range(2, 469):
    cell_range1 = ws1.cell(i, y)           #the wrong part

ws2 = wb2.active
first_row2 = list(ws2.rows)[0]
for cell in first_row2:
    if cell.value == "emailAddress":
        w = cell.column
        z = column_index_from_string(w)

for o in range(2, 469):
    cell_range2 = ws2.cell(o, z)
    cell_range2.value = cell_range1.value

path = '.../Test.xlsx'
wb2.save(path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to flip the input to `.cell()`, I guess it is `.cell(column, row)`. Or just use the keywords `.cell(column=z, row=o)`

You need a dynamic index for both of the row iterators, while keeping the column indices where you found them:

```
for o in range(2, 469):
    #note the common o for both, could also be o+1 for one if there is an offset
    ws2.cell(o, z).value = ws1.cell(o, y).value
```

Comment: That's not the part of the code that doesn't work. The question is: what's the function I need to use to copy each of the 468 cells from one workbook into the 468 cells of the second workbook? As you can see, I found a way to copy one cell (the last from the first workbook) repeatedly into the 468 cells of the second workbook. Or alternatively how can I copy a range of cells and then paste them in another workbook?

Comment: The function to copy is just assign to `.value` of a cell I guess, at least I have used it that way. Try to assign something using `.cell(column=z, row=o).value`, with some values for `z` and `o`.

Comment: Of course you need the indice also running on the left side: `ws2.cell(o, z).value = ws1.cell(i, y).value`. Did you do it like that?

Comment: But need to use a dynamic index for both of them, I add a an example above.

Comment: Yes, that is equivalent to what I wrote above. You don't need to assign to the range.

Comment: `for i in range(2, 469):
    cell_range1 = ws1.cell(i, y)
    cell_range2 = ws2.cell(i, z)
    cell_range2.value = cell_range1.value`

This code worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is actually quite easy to create such a function:

```
from openpyxl.utils import rows_from_range

def copy_range(range_str, src, dst):

    for row in rows_from_range(range_str):
        for cell in row:
            dst[cell].value = src[cell].value

    return
```

Note that range_str is a regular string such as "A1:B2"  and src and dest both have to be valid sheet objects. However, if you are copying large ranges, this might take a while, as the read/writes seem to be rather time-consuming.